# Fastest way to find elements in list

Tags: python, list

i have list of numbers from  `mrange(10**16,10**17)`( mrange is my custom range generator )
i have list of dict which contain `index:value`

```
newcombos= [{0: '5', 1: '6'}, {0: '5', 2: '1'}, {0: '5', 3: '6'}, {0: '5', 4: '1'}, {0: '5', 5: '8'}, {0: '5', 6: '5'}, {0: '5', 7: '6'}, {0: '5', 8: '5'}, {0: '5', 9: '0'}, {0: '5', 10: '5'}, {0: '5', 11: '1'}, {0: '5', 12: '8'}, {0: '5', 13: '2'}, {0: '5', 14: '9'}..]
```

taking one ie `{0: '5', 1: '6'}` represents value `5` in index `0` and value `6` in index `1`
i need to filter the `number` list which contains 5 at index 0 and 6 at index 1 and soo on for total list dict.

i am using

```
temp=[]
for j in number:
        for i in newCombos:
            index=i.keys()
            val=i.values()

            if all(str(j)[index[l]]==val[l] for l in range(0,len(val))):
                    temp.append(j)
                    break


print temp
```

Problem is it is taking more than 30 min for total loop. how can i make it fast. is there any way to may it faster

a small demo  to more clarity

let number be list of 1 to 100

```
number=[1,2,3,4,....99]
```

i have list of `dict =[{0:'5',1:'0'},{0:'6',1:'7'}]`
in the list we have only 50,67 that satisfy above dict so it should return `[50,67]` in list of 100

**edit:** if there is no clarity question i am ready to clarify

Comment: Did you find which line(s) cause it to be 'slow'?

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired input/output? I'm not clear what you're computing.

Comment: Well, the loop has to iterate over 90 quadrillion items, of course it's slow

Comment: I'm surprised it even finished

Comment: are you doing project euler?

Comment: What project Euler question is this?

Comment: If you really must iterate over the list that has 90 quadrillion items for the project, I guess the inner for loops are the problem, basically atm it loops as many times as `90000000000000000*len(newCombos)*range(0,len(val))` which is a humongous amount

Comment: you definitely don't want to bruteforce it

Comment: I don't think you need a list of all possible sequences in order to solve the problem. Maybe it would be good to let this implementation be for a moment and try to think of a different approach

Comment: `i need to filter the number list` What is `number` list?

Comment: Please check http://sscce.org/ once.

Comment: Can you please reduce the problem statement by eliminating all the unnecessary details?

Comment: So if you have `{0:'1', 2:'5'}` then possible values are `105, 115, ..., 195` is that correct? So all you want to know is how many of them are in `number` list?

Comment: Why don't you convert the dictionaries to actual numbers and then you can simply do set operations. It will be very fast.

Comment: @thefourtheye That actually depends on the initial data. For a dict `{0:'1', 10000: '2'}` you have to generate `10^9998` numbers and do lots of checks. Depending on the data this solution or mr0re1's will be faster. I think this can be heavily optimized by taking into account that `number` list is special - it's an arithmetic sequence.

Comment: please remove your comments as soon as u get response.:) it became long

Comment: BTW: you have `9*(10**16)` numbers. Empty loop in Python through that generator took me more then half an hour (actually it didn't finish, so I just stopped it). Well, my PC is not the strongest one in the world. Also the data set is too big to be stored in a Python set. Perhaps you should switch to C/C++? Otherwise I doubt you'll ever achieve better result.

Comment: @freakish there are other ways to find this in python in no time.i think my methodology is wrong. ineed to think in different way.

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар Not really, because the final step is returning the result. Let me give you a simple example: `mrange(10**16, 10**17)` and `newcombos=[{0:'0', 1:'1'}]`. This basically means that any combination starting with `01*` is valid. So your solution is an array of `10^15` elements. Simple listing all of them will take forever.

Comment: @freakish http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54138/improving-efficiency-of-the-code please check here i have given code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an **tree** `combos`:

```
[{0: '5', 1: '6'}, {1: '4', 2: '1'}, {0: '5', 3: '6'}, {0: '1', 2: '7'}]
```

became

```
{
  0: {  
    1: {
      2: {7: True}, # for {0: '1', 2: '7'}
    }
    5: {
      1: {6: True}, # for {0: '5', 1: '6'}
      3: {6: True}, # for {0: '5', 3: '6'}
    }, 
  },
  1: {
    4: {
      2: {1: True}, # for {1: '4', 2: '1'}
    }
  }
}
```

so you can check each `number` digit by digit, and break check as soon as one of condition will satisfied.

**How to build tree:**

combo `{1: 6, 0: 5}` is

`(n[0] is 5) and (n[1] is 6)` **note:** you should sort sub-conditions by position.

this condition became

`{0: {5: {1: {6: True}}}}` even-deep keys are positions, odd-deep are values

you should join this conditions in tree

**Optimization**

You can compress tree, by sharing common condition suffixes, 
it will sufficiently reduce tree-size and checking time

Comment: but one the number meet the any one condition in dict . i am break it and continuing with other number. so no chance of duplicate.

Comment: can u explain how u generated the tree

Comment: yep, my mistake, I've overlooked `break`.

Comment: can u provide little explanation how u generated the tree

Comment: Note that that depends on the initial data. If these dicts don't share common indexes, then you gain nothing.

Answer (score 1):

**`This is not answer. Just comment.`**

I wonder it's just math problem... See below....

given condition:

```
newcombos= [{0: '5', 1: '6'}, {0: '5', 2: '1'}, {0: '5', 3: '6'}, {0: '5', 4: '1'}, {0: '5', 5: '8'}, {0: '5', 6: '5'}, {0: '5', 7: '6'}, {0: '5', 8: '5'}, {0: '5', 9: '0'}, {0: '5', 10: '5'}, {0: '5', 11: '1'}, {0: '5', 12: '8'}, {0: '5', 13: '2'}, {0: '5', 14: '9'}]
```

number which satisfy given condition:

```
56
5*1
5**6
5***1
5****8
5*****5
5******6
5*******5
5********0
5*********5
5**********1
5***********8
5************2
5*************9
561618565051829
```

So I guess the answer is `561618565051829` or `5*************9`.